# How to skip input according to keywords in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr4, grammar, keyword, skip

I am new to antlr4 and wonder if it can do what I am looking for. Here is an example input:

```
There is a lot of text 
in this file that i do not care 
about
Lithium 20 g/ml
Bor that should be skipped
Potassium  300g/ml
...
```

and code:

SempredParser.g4

```
parser grammar SempredParser;
options { tokenVocab=SempredLexer ;}

file        : line+ EOF;
line        : KEYWORD (NUM UNIT)+ '\n'+;
```

SempredLexer.g4:

```
lexer grammar SempredLexer;

//lexer rules

KEYWORD     : ('Lithium' | 'Potassium' ) ;
NL          : '\n';
NUM         : [0-9]+ ('.'[0-9]+)? ;
UNIT        : 'g/ml';
UNKNOWN     : . -> skip ;
```

I would like to skip all the lines that do not contain a KEYWORD (I have around 100 KEYWORDS). Note that I only use '\n' as delimiter here and would ideally not have it parsed to the output.

I read about Island grammars in the **Definitive guide** and also tried using lexer modes but could not make it work that way. Any hints and help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would first split the input into lines and filter out those that contain any of the keywords, without even using ANTLR. After that you can feed the found lines to a parser  to get out the details. I guess that should limit the required input to parse and may even work without skipping anything anonymously.

Comment: That's actually the way i did it before and using regular expressions instead of ANTLR. I am curious, wouldn't my requirements exactly be met by Island grammars ?

  
"... island  languages  whose  sentences have  islands  of  interesting  bits  
surrounded  by  a  sea  of  stuff  we  don’t  care about."

Comment: Yes, that would be a solution, but it's way faster to cut out the unnecessary fat en gros, instead of feeding it through the lexer + parser for nothing. Depends of course on ratio useful / entire input. But unless the useless stuff is very small I would always go by only sending the lines with interesting input through the parsing pipeline. Much less waste of CPU cycles.

Comment: I get your point. For me it is more about the learning experience of what is possible with ANTLR and not so much about efficiency right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close, just avoid to define a linebreak token twice. This grammar works for me (I put it into a combined grammar file):

```
grammar IslandTest;

start: NL+ line+ EOF;
line:  KEYWORD (NUM UNIT)+ NL+;

KEYWORD: ('Lithium' | 'Potassium');
NUM:     [0-9]+ ('.' [0-9]+)?;
UNIT:    'g/ml';

NL:      '\n';
UNKNOWN: . -> skip;
```

With your input that gives me this parse tree:

[image]

Note also: you cannot avoid the NL token in your output, because you decided to make your `line` parse rule line based, which requires the newline token.

Comment: Thanks for showing me that i am on the right track. Now that this sample works I start using real input. One thing i was struggling with is that apparently all found tokens need to be consumed by the parser. I initially thought that I can just cherry pick the ones I am interested in.
BTW how did you do that awesome parse tree?

Comment: Yes, the lexer has to consume all input and it gives you an error if it sees something for which no rule exists. That's one reason why I'm no friend of using the lexer to skip unwanted input. The parse tree visualization was produced by my Visual Studio Code extension for ANTL4: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mike-lischke.vscode-antlr4.